# Count array value in array

Tags: javascript, performance

I need to construct an object with all value from same position

```
const arr = [
  [ 0, 2, .. ],
  [ 19, 4, .. ],
  [ 98, 12, .. ]
]
```

==>

```
const result = {
  0: [0, 19, 98],
  1: [2, 4, 12],
  ...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like some sort of transposition. A simple nested loop will do.

```js
const arr = [
  [0, 2],
  [19, 4],
  [98, 12]
]

var obj = {}
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    obj[j] = obj[j] || []
    obj[j].push(arr[i][j])
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```